# How do I create the wallet in paystack?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, axios

I'm trying to create the wallet API using the nodejs and Paystack as 3rd party interface. I want to use the paystack to act as the wallet so that users can donate into another user’s wallet and that user can withdraw the funds into their account or user can also transfer that amount to his bank a/c.

Is it possible that in paystack I can do perform this, I just need the roadmap or the direction to perform this task,

currently I'm creating the user in paystack , I'm not able to see the option of payout in paystack, so the alternative is using the BVN, Transaction ,subaccount and create customer API, Can anyone help me with the right direction to create the wallet in paystack

Comment: Can you share any attempts you have made at this so we can help debug? Please refer to [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Such is not available on paystack. it's just used to track and make payments.